# Can the "INTERLEAVE IN PARENT" Property be Removed From a GCP Spanner Table

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I suspect the answer to my question is "no" since I can't find any documentation that indicates how to do this - further because the property:

```
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT <parent table name>;
```

or

```
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT <parent table name> ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

actually changes how the data is physically stored - that also makes me think this isn't possible.  Lastly I couldn't find anything here:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language

That would indicate that you can remove the "interleave parent" property from a table using "alter_table".

But, thought I would ask - since I couldn't actually find anything that explicitly said - you can't removing the interleave parenting constraint/property from a table.

I suspect the only recourse for someone that wants to remove this relationship is to manually create a temp table, copy the contents of the original into the new table, delete the old table, recreate the old table without the interleave-parent, and then copy the temp table back into the new table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect the answer to my question is "no" since I can't find any documentation that indicates how to do this - further because the property:
> ...
> actually changes how the data is physically stored

Yes, you are correct. The advantage of using `INTERLEAVE IN PARENT` is better data-locality and performance and that does affect how data is stored. The only thing you can change is the `ON DELETE` part.

> I suspect the only recourse for someone that wants to remove this relationship is to manually create a temp table, copy the contents of the original into the new table, delete the old table, recreate the old table without the interleave-parent, and then copy the temp table back into the new table.

Yes, at a high level. If using a new name is not an issue (i.e. you can change the query in the application), you can probably skip using the temp tables. You may also need to consider how to handle incremental changes if this needs to happen online.